# Why my application hosted on google cloud do a kind of cache that shows wrong information to the user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM instance with a java application run on wildfly and there are some access in this application comming from the same external IP. Something happen just with my gcloud instance because when somebody do the login with a especific user, some menus shows another user as logged, and i realized that it is some kind of cache of gcloud, because if I do a refresh, shows the correct user. I did the same test in other servers and this not happen. Can you guys help about it?

Comment: I don't think that the VM holds any kind of cache. If we were speaking of App Engine, it could be, but the VM on GCP is like a VM in AWS, Azure, etc. Weird behavior, but nothing that can't be prevented from the code.

Comment: maybe I cant show as it happen exacly, but the code was verify and several tests are made. If I reboot the server, the first access is normal, but another login with another user shows the user of the first login until I just access the page again. I wanna know if someone saw this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. It was the proxy that did cache.